# Problema configurando un proxy en Ubuntu con Squid

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

estoy intentando configurar un proxy con **Squid** .

En el fichero de configuracion `/etc/squid/squid.conf`  , le he añadido esto :

```
###############################
#  PROBANDO........... ########
###############################

#http_access deny all

acl backlist1 dstdomain  minijuegos.com

http_access deny backlist1
```

En **google chrome** cuando busco proxy en la configuraciones me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando le doy a **Abrir la configuración de proxy de tu ordenador** me lleva a la configuracion de mi PC :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual le tengo puesto el host  de mi servidor proxy Squid con el puerto por defecto, pero cuando intento acceder a **minijuegos.com** otra vez.. me sigue dejando entrar. No se porque no detecta el proxy, alguien me podria ayudar ??
Estoy probando para cuando acceda a https://www.minijuegos.com/ que no me deje.